# Help about my first laser characterization setup

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, laser, education

I have done a PhD in Photonics (working on silicon growth, surface analysis and simulations).

Since two days ago, I have a new job and the first task I have is to do a laser characterization and to study the output power, voltage, current, beam divergence as a function of the temperature. I have to design a setup and buy the components for the setup.

I would appreciate if you could point me towards useful resources such as books, links, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome :)

If you know the wavelength of the laser you can estimate the power by using a photodiode and its responsivity for certain wavelengths. For optoelectronics you can read **"Optoelectronics and Photonics" by S.O. Kasap**. Also basic photodiode circuits are covered in this book.

Beam divergence can be determined, assuming you are dealing with a Gaussian beam TEM00 and are far away from the Rayleigh length, by measuring the beam width using a beam profiler (basically just a camera) at several planes in the propagation direction. I haven't checked it but I guess **"Optics" by E. Hecht** has some information about Gaussian beams.

Voltage and current measurement are quite straightforward in general. Basically any introduction to electronics would suffice to derive a setup to measure these values, but I would suggest **"The Art of Electronics" by Paul Horowitz**.

There are many more sources of course you could check, but this could be a start.